# Incrementing (or not) the contents of one column for every row

Tags: r, syntax-error, rows, apply

I have a data frame with mixed classes:

- `ratio` (factor or numeric)
- `other` (whatever)
- `error.counter` (integer)

  ```
    ratio other error.counter
  1  1.00     1             0
  2  2.00     2             0
  3  1.33     3             0
  4  1.00     4             0
  5  0.66     1             0
  6  1.00     2             0
  ```

My ultimate goal is to increment the `error.counter` when `ratio` is greater than 1.

First, try to output the concerned rows:

```
> apply(d, 1, function(x) if (as.numeric(x$ratio) > 1.00) paste(x))
Error in x$ratio : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I don't understand that error...

Though, its equivalent syntax using double brackets works:

```
> apply(d, 1, function(x) if (as.numeric(x[["ratio"]]) > 1.00) paste(x))
$`1`
NULL

$`2`
[1] "2" "2" "0"

$`3`
[1] "1.33" "3"    "0"   

$`4`
NULL

$`5`
NULL

$`6`
NULL
```

Right: rows 2 and 3 should have the error counter incremented by one. Let's do it:

```
> apply(d, 1, function(x) if (as.numeric(x[["ratio"]]) > 1.00)
                          {x[["error.counter"]] <- x[["error.counter"]] + 1})
$`1`
NULL

$`2`
[1] 1

$`3`
[1] 1

$`4`
NULL

$`5`
NULL

$`6`
NULL
```

... and check the result in our data frame:

```
> d
  ratio other error.counter
1  1.00     1             0
2  2.00     2             0
3  1.33     3             0
4  1.00     4             0
5  0.66     1             0
6  1.00     2             0
```

For a reason which still escapes me, the data frame is not updated...

So, 2 questions:

- What's the problem of using $ to refer to the columns?
- Why isn't the data frame updated?

Comment: In functional languages like R variables passed to a function are not updated. You need to assign the return value of `apply` (which won't work with the return value you have). Also, what @josilber said.

Comment: Any idea about the syntax error (question #1)?

Comment: If you just want to increment those ratios >1, `indx <- d$ratio >1;indx[indx] <- cumsum(indx[indx]); indx#[1] 0 1 2 0 0 0`

Comment: @user3341592 the reason for your syntax error is that `d` becomes a matrix when you use `apply`, and you can't use `$` notation with matrices. You would need to use `x["ratio"]` or `x[["ratio"]]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!  I must admit the error message is simply not understandable (to someone like me)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally to get the sum of a variable up to a certain point in a data frame you would use a cumulative sum, which is the function `cumsum` in R. In this case you're looking for the cumulative sum of a variable that's 1 if `ratio` is too large and 0 otherwise. You can do this with:

```
d$error.counter <- cumsum(d$ratio > 1)
d
#   ratio other error.counter
# 1  1.00     1             0
# 2  2.00     2             1
# 3  1.33     3             2
# 4  1.00     4             2
# 5  0.66     1             2
# 6  1.00     2             2
```

If you just want to set `error.counter` to 1 when the ratio exceeds 1, then you just remove the `cumsum`:

```
d$error.counter <- as.numeric(d$ratio > 1)
d
#   ratio other error.counter
# 1  1.00     1             0
# 2  2.00     2             1
# 3  1.33     3             1
# 4  1.00     4             0
# 5  0.66     1             0
# 6  1.00     2             0
```

If you want to set the error counter to 0 if there's no error and otherwise accumulate it, perhaps:

```
d$error.counter <- ifelse(d$ratio > 1, cumsum(d$ratio > 1), 0)
d
#   ratio other error.counter
# 1  1.00     1             0
# 2  2.00     2             1
# 3  1.33     3             2
# 4  1.00     4             0
# 5  0.66     1             0
# 6  1.00     2             0
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction. Though, only rows 2 and 3 have a `ratio` above 1, so these are the only lines which should have an `error.counter` equal to 1!?

Comment: @user3341592 oh, I thought you wanted to count the number of errors up to that point in the data frame. If you just want to flag the rows with errors you just remove the `cumsum` (see updated answer).

Comment: Thanks, that's it!  I thought we had to use apply for such cases... and couldn't write the right line to do so with apply...

Comment: I accepted your answer. However, would it be easy and take "no time", I'd be interested to see how you'd write the same using `apply`. Best regards

Comment: @user3341592 I definitely wouldn't use `apply` for this, but I guess you could do `d$error.counter <- apply(d, 1, function(x) if (x["ratio"] > 1) 1 else 0)`. The reason that this is a bad idea is that you're essentially looping through the rows and doing your computation one row at a time. In R it's more efficient to use vectorized operators like `cumsum` and `ifelse` that take vectors as inputs instead of single numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
ratio <- c(1.00, 2.00, 1.33, 1.00, 0.66, 1.00)
other <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2)
error.counter <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ratio, other, error.counter))

df %>% mutate(error.counter = ifelse(ratio > 1, error.counter + 1, error.counter))

#   ratio other error.counter
# 1  1.00     1             0
# 2  2.00     2             1
# 3  1.33     3             1
# 4  1.00     4             0
# 5  0.66     1             0
# 6  1.00     2             0
```